# gulp-angular-templatecache Module is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-templatecache

I am using `gulp-angular-templacache`.
I have that task that should create a module named `templates` and I added it as a dependency to my `app` module:

Configurations:

```
templateCache: {
            file: 'tempaltes.js',
            options: {
                    module: 'templates',
                    standalone: true,
                    root: 'app/'
            }
        }
```

App module:

```
var App = angular.module('app', [
    'templates']);
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('templatecache', ['clean-code'], function() {
log('Creating AngularJS $templateCache');

return gulp
    .src(config.htmltemplates)
    .pipe($.minifyHtml({empty: true}))
    .pipe($.angularTemplatecache(
        config.templateCache.file,
        config.templateCache.options
    ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
```

});

But, when I try to run this I am always getting that error message:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I tried to make the templatescache also not standalone and removing the dependency but without success...
What should I do ??

Comment: What is the sequence of file?

Comment: `file: 'tempaltes.js'`

Comment: I am asking about the sequence of script tags

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are loading *template.js*, after the module `app` definition. You can load the file before your angular `app` file

OR, Don't define a standalone module.

*Configuration*

```
templateCache: {
    file: 'tempaltes.js',
    options: {
            module: 'templates',
            standalone: false,
            root: 'app/'
    }
}
```

*Angualr*

```
//Define the module
angular.module('templates', []);
var App = angular.module('app', ['templates']);
```

Comment: Just tried that, I am getting Module 'templates' is not available
In my index.html I am injecting templates.js just after Injecting my applications js.